# Detecting incoming/outgoing whatsapp messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I just want to know if there is a way i can check for send and received whatsapp message on android, i tried to get the notifications but when the user is in whatsapp, there is no notification shown, also you can't get the sent whatsapp messages this way, is there a way that i can do it without reading its db, and if i was going to read its fb how could i accomplish it? It is encrypted like I know and the encryption between each user differs right ?